# Get available users between according to date columns between range of date

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables :

```
1) Users
2) Calendars
```

Each users have their calendar. And they can select a range of dates and mark them as :

```
=> Available (1)
=> UnAvailable (2)
```

Now initially the calendars table will be empty that means all the users are available for everyday. Now I want all the users that are available between a given range of dates. For eg: my database now looks like this :

1) Users

```
-----------------
id  name
-----------------
1    abc
2    lmn
3    xyz
```

2) Calendars

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
id      user_id        start_date            end_date           type
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1          2           2016-02-20             2016-02-25          2
2          2           2016-02-20             2016-02-25          1
3          2           2016-02-22             2016-02-24          2
```

Now if I search users between date 2016-02-20 to 2016-02-25 I should get users 1 and 3 because 2 is unavilabe in 2016-02-22 to 2016-02-24.

Also If I search between 2016-02-20 to 2016-02-22  or 2016-02-24 to 2016-02-26 then also I should get users 1 and 3.

Till now I've tried this code but this seemd to be not working.

```
$query = "
    SELECT users.id FROM users 
    WHERE id NOT IN 
    ( 
        SELECT user_id FROM calendars 
        WHERE ( '2016-02-20' >= `start_date` AND '2016-02-25' <= `end_date`) 
        OR ( '2016-02-20' <= `start_date` AND '2016-02-25' >= `end_date`) 
        OR ( `start_date` BETWEEN '2016-02-20' AND '2016-02-25') 
        OR ( `end_date` BETWEEN '2016-02-20' AND '2016-02-25')  
        AND type = 2 
    )
";

    $users = \DB::select(  \DB::raw($query) );
    $availableusers = [];
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $availableusers[] = $user->id;
    }
    return $availableusers;
```

Please help me out.

### ## UPDATE 2

The Other situation :

```
1) Users
-----------------
id  name
-----------------
1    abc
2    lmn
3    xyz

2) Calendars
------------------------------------------------------------------------
id      user_id        start_date            end_date           type
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1          2           2016-02-21             2016-02-25          2
2          2           2016-02-21             2016-02-25          1
3          3           2016-02-23             2016-02-24          2
```

Here search between '2016-02-21' and '2016-02-23' I should get the User 2 in the availbale lisy

Comment: What you have tried so far? show your code

Answer (score 1):

You can use NOT EXISTS() for this:

```
SELECT * FROM Users s
WHERE NOT EXISTS(select 1 from Calender t
                 where t.user_id = s.id and t.type = 2
                       and ((t.start_date between YourStartRange and YourEndRange)
                            OR(t.end_date between YourStartRange and YourEndRange)
                            OR(YourStartRange between t.start_date and t.end_date)))
```

This take all possibilities :

- The given range start before the range and ends between them
- The given range start between them and end after them
- The given range is between them both

Comment: The test for overlaps is simpler. Event A can be said to overlap Event B if Event A starts before Event B ends AND Event A ends after Event B starts - and remember to test for 'type'

Comment: @Pranab Try it now, I've forgot to add type filter as Strawberry pointed out

Comment: @sagi I've added a update to my query please have a look

Comment: @Pranab As I said, try it again and tell me if it still doesn't work (I've updated the answer)

Comment: @sagi Still the user 2 is not in the available list

Comment: @Pranab This doesn't make sense.. can you give me an example it doesn't work?

Comment: @sagi I've added a update to my query please have a look

Comment: @Pranab I looked at it, he is unavailable between 21 - 25 , so between 21-23 how can he be available?

Comment: @sagi you see in the next entry he made himself available again  between 21 - 25

Comment: Oh, that got more complex now.. Here is a question: if something like this happen , when he makes himself available again it will be the exact same dates? I mean, could he make him self available for 21-23 (and then he will still be unavailable for 24-25?) @Pranab

Comment: @sagi yes he can. He can make himself unavailable in any range of dates and then again make himself availabe in the same date range or a date range between the previous range.

Comment: @sagi : Consider this example : 20-25 Unavailabe, 20-25 Available, 22-26 Unavailable, 26-27 Available. so he will be available on 20, 21 and 26

Comment: Yes , I understood but it got a lot more complex now.. If I'll think of something I'll update my answer.

Comment: @sagi Thanks a lot Sagi for your help and support.

Comment: @sagi did you figured out something for this. I've had tried many queries but not able to find the solution.